# How to move reposition element in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to re position an element in a div.Basically its a span with background image.I have done the 80% part.Its working perfect when i click on it first time.It move to the desired position. But when i click on it second time it reset to its initial position.Below is my code.

I have a jsfiddle link here. https://jsfiddle.net/6q1q0wmj/

```js
var TransformRequestObj
var TransList
var DragTarget=null;
var Dragging = false;
var OffsetX = 0;
var OffsetY = 0;
jQuery(document).on('mousedown','.bx_reposioned',function(evt){
  if(!Dragging) //---prevents dragging conflicts on other draggable elements---
  {
   DragTarget = evt.target;
   //---bring this viewPort to top---
   var xcord=evt.clientX;
   var ycord = evt.clientY;
   OffsetX= OffsetX || xcord;
   OffsetY= OffsetY || ycord;
   Dragging=true;
  } 
 });
 jQuery(document).on('mousemove','.bx_reposioned',function(evt){
  if(Dragging)
  {
   //var pnt = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
   var xcord=evt.clientX;
   var ycord = evt.clientY;
   xcord -= OffsetX;
   ycord -= OffsetY;
   jQuery(this).css('transform','translate('+xcord+'px, '+ycord+'px)');
  }
 });
 
 jQuery(document).on('mouseup','.bx_reposioned',function(evt){
  Dragging = false;
  var xcord=evt.clientX;
  var ycord = evt.clientY;
  
 });
```

```css
.furniture-sprite {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bed1 {
    width: 45px;
    height: 53px;
    background:red;
}
.bed2 {
    width: 45px;
    height: 53px;
    background:blue;
}
.furniture-sprite {
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="furniture-sprite bed1 ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging bx_reposioned" style="position: absolute; width: 45px; right: auto; height: 53px; bottom: auto; left: 410.953px; top: 95px;"></span>
<span class="furniture-sprite bed2 ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging bx_reposioned" style="position: absolute; width: 45px; right: auto; height: 53px; bottom: auto; left: 410.953px; top: 95px;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle, please.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Why ask for a Fiddle when the code can and should be placed here, in a code snippet?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well, is like when you say "Google it" but people use Bing or Yahoo. With Fiddle I mean to have a working example, I don't mind where (Cdepen, jsfiddle or a nipper here, as long), as long I can see a working example. Simply in my environment we say to that to "Fiddle it".

Comment: Please include all the relevant code (HTML, CSS and JavaScript), here in a code snippet.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález *With Fiddle I mean to have a working example, I don't mind where* But, Stack Overflow does mind. External links can and will become broken over time. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base. Users who find this question at a later date won't be able to get any information from it when the link becomes bad. Whenever possible, code should be provided *in* the question. There's a perfectly good code snippet environment that most code will run in.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yep, you are right. Will try to change my mind from now on xD

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález And, does anyone really use Bing or Yahoo? ;)

Comment: Please wait i am setting it @JorgeFuentesGonzález

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6q1q0wmj/ here it is.Sorry i am late .

Comment: @ScottMarcus i think its fine now?We have snippet and jsfiddle link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the offset each time. Also, for the `mousemove` and `mouseup` you are filtering to only accept the events when they happens over the dragged element.

For the first problem you should keep your offset when you `mousedown` again and for the second problem just remove the selector filter. You will have a more fluid drag (as it will detect the drag all around the document) and also will detect the `mouseup` when you move out of the drag area.

Right now you won't notice the "out of the drag area" problem because you have not boundaries set, but you will notice if you add them.

If there are multiple elements, you should keep the offset saved on each element. This is a easy jQuery way of doing it:

Check this:

```js
var Dragging = false;

jQuery(document).on('mousedown','.bx_reposioned',function(evt){
    if(!Dragging) //---prevents dragging conflicts on other draggable elements---
    {
        //---bring this viewPort to top---
        var xcord = evt.clientX;
        var ycord = evt.clientY;
        !$(this).data("_dragOffset") && $(this).data("_dragOffset", {
            x: xcord,
            y: ycord
        }); // This will set the offset only if has no drag offset already saved
        Dragging = this;
    }
});
jQuery(document).on('mousemove', function(evt){
    if(Dragging) {
        var xcord = evt.clientX;
        var ycord = evt.clientY;
        var offset = $(Dragging).data("_dragOffset");
        xcord -= offset.x;
        ycord -= offset.y;
        jQuery(Dragging).css('transform','translate('+xcord+'px, '+ycord+'px)');
    }
});

jQuery(document).on('mouseup', function(evt){
    Dragging = false;
});
```

```css
.furniture-sprite {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bed1 {
    background-position: 0 -117px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 53px;
}
.furniture-sprite {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('http://www.builderux.com/demo5/wp-content/plugins/Builder_UX-combined-code/assets/img/furniture-sprite.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="furniture-sprite bed1 ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging bx_reposioned" style="position: absolute; width: 45px; right: auto; height: 53px; bottom: auto; left: 410.953px; top: 95px;"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the mousedown handler resets `OffsetX` and `OffsetY` even if it's already set,
if you do a check before overwriting it, it seems to work fine (line 14):

```
        OffsetX= OffsetX || xcord;
        OffsetY= OffsetY || ycord;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6q1q0wmj/1/

Comment: happy to know that helped !